# Absolute RaspPI Beginner what do i need to realize this project?

Tags: hardware, wireless

Hey guys there is so much unsorted information about the raspPI out there i don't know where to start.. My initial idea was to build an app to control my coffee machine or lights in my room..

I am not much into electronics but a friend would help me to find the right wires ;)
I know HTML5, CSS and Javascript and heard you can realize RaspPi projects with Javascript, so i'd like to use this to code my stuff.

How would this work? Can i build an app which communicates with the rasppi via wlan?

So what do i need to realize this project? What are the steps. I am so lost and i don't even understand the tutorials since they don't fit my programming languages etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1
Is it possible to build a coffee machine control app or app to control light bulbs?

Answer 
Yes. It is possible with Raspberry Pi. Their will be separate electronics involved to electrically turn on/off the power supplies etc. You will have to read more on controller circuits or ask your friend to help you. What you will be doing with the Raspberry Pi will be to provide an interface to control those devices, either manually or automatically. 
You can make Pi a server and design the server interface using HTML/Java Script. Then you will have to program the GPIO pins with Python/any other language.

This will be a bit challenging. But if you do things patiently while learning the basics it will teach you alot of interesting and important things.

Question 2
Can i build an app which communicates with the rasppi via wlan?

Answer
Yes!!. Raspberry Pi can act as a server. You can access its ports remotely on wlan to get the work done. Or else, you can install a web server(such as nginx). Think of Raspberry Pi as just another computer with programmable input output ports. Then get into each section of your project. If I were to do a room-light-controller system I'll follow these steps.

1. Design the electronic circuit. A electronic switch which accepts a voltage input and turns the light on/off.
2. Connect the above circuit to Pi using GPIO and write 'drivers'. That is a function/program which accepts light number and command as arguments.(eg: switch_on(light1), switch_off(light3) etc) This will be simple GPIO programming.
3. Build the interface.. .
4. Make it accessible over wlan/eth0 etc.

Comment: Thank you! So what are the basic steps? Buy a raspberry modul, make it a pi or webserver, program the server, program the app, connect the pi with the electronics?

Comment: thanks that is a great help for the beginning :) I guess i will have a lot of stuff to learn and a lot of time to spend on that project.. Do you know any full tutorials for any kind of project like this? Doesn't have to be light bulbs just anything like that

Comment: And which components do i have to buy to start? I understand there a different moduls and further hardware to add on

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is curious if i have figured it out.  YES is did.. i have started from knowing nothing to creating my project.. you can see it here: [Motivation System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mapi_clVRhU)